# Redirection 301 from /%postname%.html to default

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, post

I want to change the permalinks from /%postname%.html to defaulte .for example ( http://www.morzak.net/?p=123)

I know how to do that from Worpdress Admin panel. But I got more than 30000 post, so I want to know please if is any chance to make a redirection from .htacess for old my posts with /%postname%.html redirect to defaulte .for example (http://www.morzak.net/?p=123)

Comment: Do you want to all the `/something.html` and `/anotherthing.html` and `/anything.html` to redirect to `/?p=123`

Comment: yes i  want redirection all permalinks from /%postname%.html to defaulte